# Como determinar a localização aproximada do usuário pelo IP?

Tags: ip, geolocalização

Quando utilizo motores de busca para certas pesquisas, principalmente relacionadas a mapas ou estabelecimentos comerciais, esses sistemas geralmente me servem resultados relevantes para a minha localização geográfica.

Quando estou no PC, os motores de busca podem até não conhecer minha posição geográfica com precisão de GPS, mas sabem ao menos em que cidade eu estou.

Acredito que isso seja determinado pelo endereço IP, dado que geralmente uma faixa de endereços específica é fornecida pelo provedor para regiões bem determinadas.

Mas a nível de implementação, como é feita essa determinação? Existe fórmula para determinar a cidade ou região do usuário a partir de seu endereço? Ou ao menos um provedor conhecido do qual possamos consumir um serviço para obter essa informação?

Comment: Lembrei na hora [desse XKCD](http://xkcd.com/195/)... Infelizmente não encontrei nenhuma informação seja no fórum, no blog post ou no slashdot sobre como esse mapa foi feito (não procurei a fundo, entretanto). E pelo que eu li [aqui](http://www.iplocation.net/), a maioria das bases de dados de geolocalização por IP é comercial (paga), e a qualidade das mesmas varia bastante.

Comment: Não responde a sua pergunta, mas pode ser um começo. Encontrei [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/07/05/vb_ipurl.htm) uma relação país/faixa de IP.

Comment: Vale também lembrar que essa informação é orgânica (muda com frequência) e ad hoc (a distribuição dos ips é feita pelo ICANN e os banco de dados disponíveis por aí são construídos parte com essa base do ICANN e parte através de amostras estatísticas). Isso significa que o melhor serviço de geoip oferece não mais que 90 a 95% de segurança quanto ao país e não mais que 80-90% com relação a informação da cidade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da uma olhada aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-record-by-name.php

Usamos isso nosso site (www.ansb-brasil.org). Se vc escreve usando o formulário de contato, quando o site agradece você, ele indica o IP, o pais, e a cidade de você.

De verdade, isso não dá exatamente o nome da sua cidade, mas o nome do ponto de acesso internet de você.

Comment: O fato de isso ser uma função oficial do PHP me anima. Vou testar de casa mais tarde :)

Comment: Cuidado; antes de usar, faz um "PhpInfo()" para ver se o PHP que vc tem, tem esta possibilidade. Tambem, tem empresa de hospedagem que usam um sistema diferente. Sou em Brasilia mas nos usamos um hospedagem da Europa que oferece um sistema um pouco diferente do Geiop (temos $_SERVER[GEOIP] por exmplo)

Answer (score 8):

### IP GEOLOCATION

Isso na verdade é muito simples e funciona da seguinte maneira:

- As operadoras fornecem números IP's de acordo com uma faixa
- O registro da faixa é feito por localidade
- Dependendo da quantidade isso pode ser um prédio, rua, bairro ou cidade
- Com o intuito de facilitar o rastreamento de crimes essa informação é atualizada  em um banco de dados
- As operadoras fazem intercâmbio dessas informações com os seus reguladores
- Uma vez por mês esse banco é atualizado para o público

  Esse banco é o **GeoLite Database**.
  Um arquivo em formato binário ou CSV, com todos os blocos IP's atuais:
  [GeoIP Legacy Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/)

  Existem diversas formar para localizar um IP nesse banco.
  Dentre as maneiras prontas estão:
- [GeoLite CSV Java - Exemplo simples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/)
- [GeoIP2 Apache - Módulo para o Servidor Apache](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/)
- [GeoIP2 Databases Binários - Exemplos avançados em várias linguagens de programação](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/)

Answer (score 6):

Sem querer fazer um jabá, mas já fazendo, eu tenho uma biblioteca chamada [`WallaceMaxters\IPInfo`](https://github.com/wallacemaxters/ipinfo), que pega a informação de um determinado IP.

Veja um exemplo de uso:

```
 IPInfo::get('8.8.8.8')->getCountry();
```

Ela usa internamente a API do `ipinfo.io`.

Se você quiser um exemplo, acesse a url a baixo para capturar as informações:

http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json

Como já foi dito nas respostas anteriores, você não consegue determinar a localização exata da pessoa. Talvez apenas aproximada ou até apenas dentro do país.