# É possível obter informações de local do usuário através de seu ip?

Tags: ip

Existe alguma possibilidade usando a programação de se obter localidades de um suposto visitante ao seu website?

> Exemplo: "Fulano de Tal" com o ip: 192.168.254.1 visitou o meu site:
>   www.meusite.com.br

Mediante esse ip obtido posso determinar com precisão informações geográficas de tal usuário? Os detalhes de localidade que me refiro são o **país**, o **estado**, a **cidade** e se possível o **bairro**.

Quero saber se através da programação (independente da linguagem) posso obter tais dados de um visitante do meu site.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como determinar a localização aproximada do usuário pelo IP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34958/como-determinar-a-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-aproximada-do-usu%C3%A1rio-pelo-ip)

Comment: show de bola Dener Carvalho, não tinha visto aqui :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{
    alert("O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position){
   alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);  
}
```