# PHP: mapa de localização dos usuários através de IP com geolocalização

Tags: php, javascript, html, mapas

Boa Noite , eu tenho no banco de dados da minha empresa com varios endereços de IP ( em formato de histórico ) e o IP atual do usuário que acessa o meu site.

Gostaria de saber sé consigo com esse dados montar um mapa do acesso , mostrando quais países eu tenho o maior fluxo de usuários .

O sistema automaticamente já determina a sigla do país através do php e de um banco de dados de GeoIp que configurei , gostaria de saber então como organizar esses dados em um mapa.

Comment: Pode usar uma API pronta: http://www.infosniper.net/services.php

Comment: aqui no próprio Stack Overflow em português você tem a resposta. [Clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34958/como-determinar-a-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-aproximada-do-usu%C3%A1rio-pelo-ip).

Comment: @RpgBoss , ela consegue montar os mapas de calor?Pelo que vi ela me retorna dados que já possuo.

Comment: @MarceloÁgil a localização eu ja tenho , quero montar um mapa com ela.

Comment: Ah tah, você quer montar um mapa igual ao do WordPress.

Comment: Eu nunca vi esse do Wordpress , eu quero montar algo eficiente porque são 3 mil usuários , 3 mil IPS , então fica ruim puxar os dados .

Comment: O Wordpress tem uma menu no painel de controle, onde você pode analisar as visitas do dia, da semana, do mês ou geral (desde o início do registro), e ele distribui no mapa mundi com níveis de cores (Quanto mais vermelho mais visitas) dos países pra ver qual a maior frequência de visitas. Não é dificil fazer, mas leva algum tempo, por isso sugerir baixar uma API pronta. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J8Ko.png

Answer (score 0):

Se você ja tem o país que o usuário está você pode fazer de diversas formas, entre elas:

1 - usar a API do Google Maps e usar o mapa de calor
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap?hl=pt-br

2 - Você pode montar o mapa mundi em SVG (no google tem varios sites para fazer download) e criar uma coleção de cores e conforme a quantidade de acessos você usa a cor para pintar aquele país.

Comment: OI amigo , eu consigo montar esse mapa sem utilização de APIs?

Comment: Quando conseguir vai praticamente ter criado uma API sem perceber :)

Comment: Eu digo API como da Google .

Comment: olá, você ja tem as siglas dos paises em sua base de dados...então você consegue criar um degrade conforme a quantidade num range que voce determinar. Feito isso, basta pegar os SVGs do mapa mundo e colorir conforme esse degrade.

Comment: Sim , isso é o facil amigo o problema é na horar de gerar e comparar os IPs com o da base de dados do GEOIP.

Comment: Torna-se custoso pro servidor  , o mysql fica em 100% de uso da CPU com 2 mil ips.

Comment: acho que o melhor é vc criar um processo a parte que faz essa comparação do IP com a base de dados e atualiza a tabela já com o valor certo. Deixa esse processo em paralelo rodando de hora em hora pegando os novos IPs dentro desse range de hora... ou seja, vc vai ter um delay de 1h para mostrar as infos.