# Transformar número de IP em localização

Tags: javascript, csv

Eu recebo um arquivo em *.csv* com dados de alguns usuários.

```
NOME | E-MAIL | IP | DATA
```

Não consta localização.
Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu pegar o número de IP e transformar na localização.

Existem serviços na internet que informam a localização quando um IP é informado. A diferença é que eu possuo mais de um número de IP, será uma lista.

Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso e não sei se isso é possível. 
Pensei em fazer um **html** com um *input*, onde após eu fazer o upload desse arquivo, ele fizesse essa conversão.
Pensei em algo em **JavaScript**.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como determinar a localização aproximada do usuário pelo IP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34958/como-determinar-a-localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-aproximada-do-usu%c3%a1rio-pelo-ip)

Comment: @Bacco Não. Pois, eu gostaria de saber como converter uma lista.

Comment: Seria o caso de focar a pergunta no que quer saber. Se não sabe iterar e extrair o IP da linha, pergunte isso. Se o problema é como chamar a API dentro do loop, mostre a API que escolheu e sua tentativa. Fica a sugestão de ler [ask] e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70). Aqui não é um site de terceirização de serviços onde você passa 3 problemas numa pergunta só, e o pessoal faz pra você. Tente focar na duvida exata, que facilita.

Comment: Eu só não editei sua pergunta pq estragaria as respostas dadas, mas essa seria a verdadeira, pelo que vc descreveu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QlNZ.png - se partir sempre do problema real, não ocupa o tempo dos colegas, como feito abaixo, que atestam a interpretação como duplicata (ou seja, na verdade o fechamento deveria ser como "não clara", pois vieram 2 respostas elaboradas que não entenderam também)

Comment: Se é uma lista basta chamar recursivamente a função, com while, for ou afins, ou até com callbacks, já que o caso é javascript.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart e outra... gastamos tempo respondendo sua pergunta  você sequer fez um comentário nem que seja do tipo "então não é isso galera". Só quero deixar essa observação

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a api http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Exemplo:

```
GET - http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201
```

RETORNO:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "country": "United States",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "region": "CA",
  "regionName": "California",
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "zip": "94105",
  "lat": "37.7898",
  "lon": "-122.3942",
  "timezone": "America\/Los_Angeles",
  "isp": "Wikimedia Foundation",
  "org": "Wikimedia Foundation",
  "as": "AS14907 Wikimedia US network",
  "query": "208.80.152.201"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples, existem vários sites que fornecem esse tipo de serviço via API, um deles é o [ipstack](https://ipstack.com/product) que eu encontrei e é gratuito(máx de 10.000 requests por mês). 
A vantagem do ipstack é que ele fornece várias informações adicionais, como por exemplo a bandeira do pais, DDI, código de continente e outros.

Basta você se cadastrar e receberá uma chave de API, a utilização é bem simples:

```
http://api.ipstack.com/<ip>?access_key=<chave de api>
```

Como criei uma conta já tenho uma chave de API(não tem problema posta-la aqui)

`http://api.ipstack.com/191.19.145.134?access_key=dd66d448ad3762f3480cbd96faddb276`

A resposta é:

```
{
    "ip":"191.19.145.134",
    "type":"ipv4",
    "continent_code":"SA",
    "continent_name":"South America",
    "country_code":"BR",
    "country_name":"Brazil",
    "region_code":"SP",
    "region_name":"Sao Paulo",
    "city":"S\u00e3o Paulo",
    "zip":"01323",
    "latitude":-23.5733,
    "longitude":-46.6417,
    "location":{
        "geoname_id":3448439,
        "capital":"Bras\u00edlia",
        "languages":[
            {
                "code":"pt",
                "name":"Portuguese",
                "native":"Portugu\u00eas"
            }
        ],
        "country_flag":"http:\/\/assets.ipstack.com\/flags\/br.svg",
        "country_flag_emoji":"\ud83c\udde7\ud83c\uddf7",
        "country_flag_emoji_unicode":"U+1F1E7 U+1F1F7",
        "calling_code":"55",
        "is_eu":false
    }
}
```

Segue um exemplo prático, lembrando que não funcionara em requisições HTTPS(portanto não vai dar para testar direto no Stackoverflow).

```js
var api_key = "dd66d448ad3762f3480cbd96faddb276";

function LocalizaIP(ip) {
console.log("http://api.ipstack.com/"+ip+"?access_key="+api_key);
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://api.ipstack.com/"+ip+"?access_key="+api_key,   
  }).done(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
   });
};

LocalizaIP("191.19.145.134");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```